# Gracenote Multiple global Ids for album is showing

Tags: gracenote

I'm trying build an android sample based on the currently existing sample. Im new to Gracenote Feature. While checking through the sample MusiIDAssetFetch.java, the below codes are used to get album

findAlbums( "Supernatural", "Africa Bamba", "Santana",null,null );

My doubt is why Im getting albumcount as 4 while Im checking for the album "Supernatural". Im supposed to get a unique global Id for album Supernatural.
But here I'm getting four different ids and while checking tracks using a custom function, track count changes, but all four album have the song Africa Bamba.

Please help, why Im getting four Ids for album Supernatural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Best Practices for MusicID Text Searches' pages in the document.

If you pass in 'Album Title', 'Contributor Name', and 'Track Title' it is used in the following way.

> Use all information:
>
> - Album
> - Album's Primary Artist
> - Matched Track if available
> - Matched Track's Artist if available

If you want just a single best result. Try calling the following API before the lookup.

`GnMusicId.options().resultSingle(true);`